# how to do the the routing for different node microservices using docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm creating different node micro services using Docker. I'm planning to use the same ip address and different port for every service as a routing solution, but for now each service has it is own ip address, how to make it commun fot all the containers? 
Is there any tool that will facilitate routing?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question looks a bit broad. Can you add a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This includes what you have tried, what goes wrong, what would be the expected behavior.

Comment: I'm having 2 containers, each with an ip address "172.18.0.4" and "172.18.0.3" . I want to use just one ip address for both of them, and then do the routing based on the port number.

Answer (score 0):

if you're making route from outside docker, just expose ports from your docker IP server.

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 my_image_node_service_1  
docker run -d -p 3001:3000 my_image_node_service_2
```

and now with `ip_server_docker:3000` you have access on **service_1:3000**, and  `ip_server_docker:3001` you have access to **service_2:3000**.